# Why ParallelTable warns where Table runs quietly?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, parallelization

I have a code involving `ParametricNDSolveValue` and `FindRoot` to find a trajectory [actually, trajectory of a line that everywhere is normal to magnetic field] passing through a given point {rn,zn} on the rz plane. First I call for `ParametricNDSolveValue` to find  trajectory zs[z0] that starts from the point {0,z0} on the axis z:

```
dzdr$[r_, z_] /; r < 1/10^5 = (
 r (-9 Sin[2 z] + 4 Sin[4 z]))/(-9 + 9 Cos[2 z] - 2 Cos[4 z]);

dzdr$[r_, z_] /; 
  r >= 1/10^5 = (2 r (9 BesselI[1, 2 r] Sin[2 z] - 
      2 BesselI[1, 4 r] Sin[4 z]))/(18 r + 2 r^3 - 
    9 r BesselI[0, 2 r] Cos[2 z] - 9 BesselI[1, 2 r] Cos[2 z] - 
    9 r BesselI[2, 2 r] Cos[2 z] + 2 r BesselI[0, 4 r] Cos[4 z] + 
    BesselI[1, 4 r] Cos[4 z] + 2 r BesselI[2, 4 r] Cos[4 z]);

pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{D[z[r], r] == dzdr$[r, z[r]], 
   z[0] == z0}, z, {r, 0, 1.5}, {{z0, -(\[Pi]/2), \[Pi]/2}}]

zs[{r_?NumericQ, z0_?NumericQ}] := pfun[z0][r]
```

At the second step I define function getZ0[{rn,zn}] that calls for `FindRoot` to find starting  point z0 for the trajectory that passes through a given point {rn,zn}:

```
getZ0[{rn_?NumericQ, zn_?NumericQ}, z0Start_?NumericQ] := Module[
  {sol}
  , sol = 
   FindRoot[zs[{rn, z0}] - zn, {z0, z0Start, -(\[Pi]/2), \[Pi]/2}];
  sol[[1, 2]]
  ]
getZ0[{rn_?NumericQ, zn_?NumericQ}] := getZ0[{rn, zn}, zn]
```

Finally, I want to evaluate getZ0 on a rectangular grid using `Table`:

```
Table[{{rn, zn}, getZ0[{rn, zn}]}, {zn, -(\[Pi]/2), \[Pi]/2, 
  1/2 \[Pi]/2}, {rn, 0, 1, 0.5}]
```

This works fine. However substuting `Table` with `ParallelTable` results in sequence of Warnings of the types: `FindRoot::lstol`, `ParametricNDSolveValue::ndsz`, `InterpolatingFunction::dmval`.
However both routines seemed to give same results.

To say truth, the differential equation which is solved by `ParametricNDSolveValue` is singular in two poins (where magnetic field is zero). But I wonder why there are no warnings when I use `Table` rather than `ParallelTable`?

Comment: With Mathematica 12.1 I also get warning messages for Table.

Comment: @RolfMertig: getZ0[{rn, zn}] /. {rn -> 1, zn -> \[Pi]/4} yields lot of warnings in Mathematica 9.0 but not in version 12. Both versions give same result 0.311897. I assume that the warnings are caused by singularity 0/0.